# find maximum index with same index in other axis in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array in python like this that contains coordinate of some points that for each row the first column is x and the second is y

```
[[1,2],
[1,5],
[1,3],
[2,4],
[2,3]]
```

I need to find points with the maximum value of y for points with the same x value. for the above array, I require this output

```
[[1,5],
[2,4]]
```

Note that I should do this without any loop in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, *Numpy* does not support grouping, but you can use respective
*Pandas* function and then convert back to a *Numpy* array or even plain
*pythonic* list:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(a).groupby(0).max().reset_index().values.tolist()
```

I assume that *a* is your source *Numpy* array, created e.g. with:

```
a = np.array([[1,2], [1,5], [1,3], [2,4], [2,3]])
```

Note also that the other solution contains a *for* loop embedded in
a list comprehension, but you want a solution **without any loop**
(just like mine).

Answer (score 0):

See if this works using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby

values = [[1,2], [1,5], [1,3], [2,4], [2,3]]

print(
    [max(v) for _, v in groupby(values, key = lambda x : x[0])]
)
```

---

```
[[1, 5], [2, 4]]
```